# Windows CMD: How to create symbolic link to executable file?

Tags: windows, shell

My goal is to add a few executables to my PATH (for example, chrome), so that I can call

```
> chrome
```

from the command prompt and it will launch Chrome.

I know I could add Chrome's containing directory to my path (`set PATH=%PATH%<chrome_path_here>;`), but since I have a few executables I want to add, I'd rather make a new bin directory that contains symbolic links to the actual executables and just add that single directory to my PATH.

The Chrome executable is located at

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

So I tried

```
> mklink chrome.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
```

That successfully creates a symbolic link for the files (says so in output, and upon examining with `> dir`).  I know my PATH is set up correctly, b/c when I run `> where chrome` it finds my new symbolic link.

However, when I try to execute chrome with my new link, nothing happens.  A new empty window should appear, but nothing happens.  No error message in the command prompt or anything.

What am I doing wrong?  Am I misunderstanding symlinks in Windows?  This is the approach I use in Linux all the time, but I'm new to Windows Cmd.

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Most programs will not run from places other than they install location - which is exactly what happens when you try to run it from symlink.

It would be much easier to create CMD/BAT files in that folder with matching names which will launch programs from locations you want:

```
REM chrome.cmd
start /b cmd /c "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" %*
```

Comment: Cool, thanks for the info!  I put that code into a file called 'chrome.bat', and now it works

Comment: Another option would be a shortcut, though you'd need to add .lnk to your PATHEXT variable.

Comment: If you add @echo off to the beginning of your CMD/BAT the commands in your file won't be echoed when you execute it.

Comment: "Most programs will not run from places other than they install location" is a bold claim. There are plenty of self-contained executables out there that run just fine from whatever location you copy/link them to.

Answer (score 11):

With Windows 7 I confirm that *symlinks do not work*, are simply ignored as reported in the original question.

As [Harry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/886887/harry-johnston) states in his comment, shortcuts **do** work, and to me are simpler and easier than writing a separate script for each new command I want to enable under CMD.

He states that you need to add .lnk to your PATHEXT variable in order to do this.  I affirm that this does work, and with .lnk added to PATHEXT I can simply enter the name portion of the shortcut to run the command.  For example if my shortcut is named "sublime.lnk" and PATHEXT includes .lnk, I can execute the link with the simple command "sublime".  Nice!

As an alternative I found that PATHEXT need not be modified if I simply type in the full name of the shortcut, including the .lnk, at my CMD prompt.  E.g., I created a shortcut named "sublime.lnk" under %HOMEPATH%/bin, pointing to "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2\sublime_text.exe".

Now by placing %HOMEPATH%\bin in my %PATH% I can run sublime via the command "sublime.lnk".

Either of the above are the best way I know of giving access to various commands from around Windows' filesystem from a CMD prompt.  I'm not a Windows expert though, and welcome a better or more standardized solution to this problem.

---

P.S.: I just found out the hard way that you need to ensure the "Start in:" property of any shortcut you use in this fashion is blanked out, or your program will not start in the directory you invoke the shortcut from.

---

P.P.S.: On a related note, I discovered how to run Windows Explorer (or its replacement) on the directory your CMD session is logged in to: `start .`.

Comment: 2 questions: (1) Does this approach allow for switches to commands? (2) Are there any caveats at all using this method? ... Oddly, for me, on Windows 10 version 2004, adding a symlink to an exe in my bin folder seems to work. That is to say, the I can run the exe as a command without extension (it's recognized by the terminal) but I get complaints of missing modules and stuff, which I don't get if I run the exe via its full path.

Comment: @Henrik, thank you for your interest.  As I state in my answer, *I'm not a Windows expert.*  Therefore, please apply my observations with caution.  I find that command line options *do* work using this approach.  I am only guessing, but suspect that if a command behaves differently via symlinks it may be extracting its execution path from the command line and using that information to locate other components ("modules and stuff" as you put it).