# How do I get my Windows7 symlink to execute from command line?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, path, symlink

I have a couple of batch files I want to use regularly, so I decided I would drop them as symlinks into a binaries folder in my path. The idea being that I would use them like I would any other command, without having to change directories. E.g.

```
> odbimport -u User -f filename
```

where odbimport is my symlink to the batch file odbimport.bat.

The process I used to make the symlinks is as follows:

```
C:\Users\user>mklink C:\utils\odbimport C:\util-files\odbimport.bat
symbolic link created for C:\utils\odbimport <<===>> C:\util-files\odbimport.bat

C:\Users\user>path
Path=C:\....;C:\utils\

C:\Users\user>where odbimport
C:\utils\odbimport
```

From what I've seen, it looks like I've made the symlink, and the path knows where to find it.

However, after I've made my symlink and attempt to execute, I get:

```
C:\Users\user> odbimport -u me -f somefile
'odbimport' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. "
```

I've been looking for an answer to this with no success. Everything I find seems to deal more with how to create working symlinks than addressing my issue. The closest thing I found was [this](https://superuser.com/questions/304093/executing-symbolic-link-to-exe-the-specified-path-does-not-exist). This is essentially my question, except kinda backwards because I don't really want to run the symlinks from Windows Explorer. I have also tried adding .LNK to my PATHEXT variable as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322980/windows-cmd-how-to-create-symbolic-link-to-executable-file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `.bat` extension to the symlink you create because on Windows .bat extension is necessary to tell the system it's actually an executable batch file. You will still be able to run the file by typing its name only.

```
mklink C:\utils\odbimport.bat C:\util-files\odbimport.bat
```

NTFS hardlinks can be used when source and target are on the same volume, the advantage is that such clones may be executed from Windows Explorer unlike symlinks:

- `mklink /h C:\utils\odbimport.bat C:\util-files\odbimport.bat`
- `fsutil hardlink create C:\utils\odbimport.bat C:\util-files\odbimport.bat`

Comment: If I were to add the .bat extension to my symlink, then I would have to call "odbimport.bat" instead of "odbimport" correct? While that looks less pretty, if it means I can call "odbimport.bat" in any dir and have it work, then this will be a solution. I'll test it and get back to you.

Comment: Looks like this still doesn't fix my issue. My steps: 1. Made the symlink into "odbimport.bat" 2. Rechecked path has folder location to look in, and that "where" returns the correct location of my symlink. 3. Called "odbimport.bat" in a folder other than the original location. Attempt failed with the error "The system cannot open the device of file specified". I wonder if this is an access permissions problem.

Comment: 1. Unlike *nix on Windows `.bat` extension is necessary to tell the system it's actually an executable batch file. To invoke it you don't have to specify the extension. 2. Try with a different folder and a new .bat file that only has something primitive like `echo OK` 3. And yeah, make sure the volume is NTFS.

Comment: I didn't realize that I could call .bat's without having to tell the system the extension. That's actually great news, and makes a bunch of sense looking back on it. That bit of knowledge led to my solution. It seems I needed to hardlink, instead defaulting mklink to softlink. I noticed when I looked at the symlink in Windows Explorer that even with the .bat extension it said the file was a symlink file. I guess windows command line won't run softlinks, even if they point to a .bat file.

Comment: Windows 7 command prompt runs symlinks created in default mode, I've tested it.